# How to force Django every time recreate .pyc files?

Tags: python, django, git, pycharm

I start using Django in PyCharm recently with git. Sometimes I have problem with running the server it shows some errors which I fixed. In order to solve this problem I should every time manually remove .pyc files. And run server again. How I can force it two override .pyc files every time when I compile my source?

> Thanks for @jbat100 and @Leonardo.Z. I figured it out. I pass PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1. And it work as a magic. However sadly I can just accept only one answer I hope @jbat100 will not be angry with me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Python 2.6 Python can be prevented from writing .pyc or .pyo files by supplying the **-B** switch to the Python interpreter, or by setting the **PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE** environment variable before running the interpreter.

This setting is available to Python programs as the `sys.dont_write_bytecode variable`, and Python code can change the value to modify the interpreter’s behaviour.  via: [Interpreter Changes](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.6.html#interpreter-changes)

Comment: Just clarification. Does PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE have value?

Comment: According documentation there is no value for this env variable. PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE
If this is set, Python won’t try to write .pyc or .pyo files on the import of source modules. This is equivalent to specifying the -B option.

Comment: are you using virtualenv with Pycharm?

Comment: Yes. And it works after I pass for PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE value 1. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 2):

Leonardo's anwer is probably what you're looking for but you can also just remove the `.pyc` files with the shell

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

There's a [Django snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/899/) also to do that

```
import os
directory = os.listdir('.')
for filename in directory:
    if filename[-3:] == 'pyc':
        print '- ' + filename
        os.remove(filename)
```

You can also check out the [compileall](http://docs.python.org/2/library/compileall.html) utility which is used to compile python sources and has options to force recompilation.

Comment: You are right. His answer is just what I want. However it does not work in PyCharm I just wondering why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I use the **following code** to achieve that:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('find . -name "*.py[co]" -delete', shell=True)
```

To use it as a **manage.py command**, you can do the following.

Place this code in: `<app_name>/management/commands/delete_pyc.py`

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):    
    help = """Delete all .pyc/.pyo files"""    
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        import subprocess
        subprocess.call('find . -name "*.py[co]" -delete', shell=True)
```

To run do:

```
python manage.py delete_pyc
```